# Write a dataframe formatted to a csv sheet

Tags: r, statistics

I am having a dataframe which looks like that:

```
> (eventStudyList120_After)
         Dates Company Returns Market Returns Abnormal Returns
1   25.08.2009            4.81     0.62595516         4.184045
2   26.08.2009            4.85     0.89132960         3.958670
3   27.08.2009            4.81    -0.93323011         5.743230
4   28.08.2009            4.89     1.00388875         3.886111
5   31.08.2009            4.73     2.50655343         2.223447
6   01.09.2009            4.61     0.28025201         4.329748
7   02.09.2009            4.77     0.04999239         4.720008
8   03.09.2009            4.69    -1.52822071         6.218221
9   04.09.2009            4.89    -1.48860354         6.378604
10  07.09.2009            4.85    -0.38646531         5.236465
11  08.09.2009            4.89    -1.54065680         6.430657
12  09.09.2009            5.01    -0.35443455         5.364435
13  10.09.2009            5.01    -0.54107231         5.551072
14  11.09.2009            4.89     0.15189458         4.738105
15  14.09.2009            4.93    -0.36811321         5.298113
16  15.09.2009            4.93    -1.31185921         6.241859
17  16.09.2009            4.93    -0.53398643         5.463986
18  17.09.2009            4.97     0.44765285         4.522347
19  18.09.2009            5.01     0.81109101         4.198909
20  21.09.2009            5.01    -0.76254262         5.772543
21  22.09.2009            4.93     0.11309704         4.816903
22  23.09.2009            4.93     1.64429117         3.285709
23  24.09.2009            4.93     0.37294212         4.557058
24  25.09.2009            4.93    -2.59894035         7.528940
25  28.09.2009            5.21     0.29588776         4.914112
26  29.09.2009            4.93     0.49762314         4.432377
27  30.09.2009            5.41     2.17220569         3.237794
28  01.10.2009            5.21     1.67482716         3.535173
29  02.10.2009            5.25    -0.79014302         6.040143
30  05.10.2009            4.97    -2.69996146         7.669961
31  06.10.2009            4.97     0.18086490         4.789135
32  07.10.2009            5.21    -1.39072582         6.600726
33  08.10.2009            5.05     0.04210020         5.007900
34  09.10.2009            5.37    -1.14940251         6.519403
35  12.10.2009            5.13     1.16479551         3.965204
36  13.10.2009            5.37    -2.24208216         7.612082
37  14.10.2009            5.13     0.41327193         4.716728
38  15.10.2009            5.21     1.54473332         3.665267
39  16.10.2009            5.13    -1.73781565         6.867816
40  19.10.2009            5.01     0.66416288         4.345837
41  20.10.2009            5.09    -0.27007314         5.360073
42  21.10.2009            5.13     1.26968917         3.860311
43  22.10.2009            5.01     0.29432965         4.715670
44  23.10.2009            5.01     1.73758937         3.272411
45  26.10.2009            5.21     0.38854011         4.821460
46  27.10.2009            5.21     2.72671890         2.483281
47  28.10.2009            5.21    -1.76846884         6.978469
48  29.10.2009            5.41     2.95523593         2.454764
49  30.10.2009            5.37    -0.22681024         5.596810
50  02.11.2009            5.33     1.38835160         3.941648
51  03.11.2009            5.33    -1.83751398         7.167514
52  04.11.2009            5.21    -0.68721323         5.897213
53  05.11.2009            5.21    -0.26954741         5.479547
54  06.11.2009            5.21    -2.24083342         7.450833
55  09.11.2009            5.17     0.39168239         4.778318
56  10.11.2009            5.09    -0.99082271         6.080823
57  11.11.2009            5.17     0.07924735         5.090753
58  12.11.2009            5.81    -0.34424802         6.154248
59  13.11.2009            6.21    -2.00230195         8.212302
60  16.11.2009            7.81     0.48655978         7.323440
61  17.11.2009            7.69    -0.21092848         7.900928
62  18.11.2009            7.61     1.55605852         6.053941
63  19.11.2009            7.21     0.71028798         6.499712
64  20.11.2009            7.01    -2.38596631         9.395966
65  23.11.2009            7.25     0.55334705         6.696653
66  24.11.2009            7.21    -0.54239847         7.752398
67  25.11.2009            7.25     3.36386413         3.886136
68  26.11.2009            7.01    -1.28927630         8.299276
69  27.11.2009            7.09     0.98053264         6.109467
70  30.11.2009            7.09    -2.61935612         9.709356
71  01.12.2009            7.01    -0.11946242         7.129462
72  02.12.2009            7.21     0.17152317         7.038477
73  03.12.2009            7.21    -0.79343095         8.003431
74  04.12.2009            7.05     0.43919792         6.610802
75  07.12.2009            7.01     1.62169804         5.388302
76  08.12.2009            7.01     0.74055990         6.269440
77  09.12.2009            7.05    -0.99504492         8.045045
78  10.12.2009            7.21    -0.79728245         8.007282
79  11.12.2009            7.21    -0.73784636         7.947846
80  14.12.2009            6.97    -0.14656077         7.116561
81  15.12.2009            6.89    -1.42712116         8.317121
82  16.12.2009            6.97     0.95988962         6.010110
83  17.12.2009            6.69     0.22718293         6.462817
84  18.12.2009            6.53    -1.46958638         7.999586
85  21.12.2009            6.33    -0.21365446         6.543654
86  22.12.2009            6.65    -0.17256757         6.822568
87  23.12.2009            7.05    -0.59940253         7.649403
88  24.12.2009            7.05             NA               NA
89  25.12.2009            7.05             NA               NA
90  28.12.2009            7.05    -0.22307263         7.273073
91  29.12.2009            6.81     0.76736750         6.042632
92  30.12.2009            6.81     0.00000000         6.810000
93  31.12.2009            6.81    -1.50965723         8.319657
94  01.01.2010            6.81             NA               NA
95  04.01.2010            6.65     0.06111069         6.588889
96  05.01.2010            6.65    -0.13159651         6.781597
97  06.01.2010            6.65     0.09545081         6.554549
98  07.01.2010            6.49    -0.32727619         6.817276
99  08.01.2010            6.81    -0.07225296         6.882253
100 11.01.2010            6.81     1.61131397         5.198686
101 12.01.2010            6.57    -0.40791980         6.977920
102 13.01.2010            6.85    -0.53016383         7.380164
103 14.01.2010            6.93     1.82016604         5.109834
104 15.01.2010            6.97    -0.62552046         7.595520
105 18.01.2010            6.93    -0.80490241         7.734902
106 19.01.2010            6.77     2.02857647         4.741424
107 20.01.2010            6.93     1.68204556         5.247954
108 21.01.2010            6.89     1.02683875         5.863161
109 22.01.2010            6.90     0.96765669         5.932343
110 25.01.2010            6.73    -0.57603687         7.306037
111 26.01.2010            6.81     0.50990350         6.300096
112 27.01.2010            6.81     1.64994011         5.160060
113 28.01.2010            6.61    -1.13511086         7.745111
114 29.01.2010            6.53    -0.82206204         7.352062
115 01.02.2010            7.03    -1.03993428         8.069934
116 02.02.2010            6.93     0.61692305         6.313077
117 03.02.2010            7.73     2.53012795         5.199872
118 04.02.2010            7.97     1.96223075         6.007769
119 05.02.2010            9.33    -0.76549820        10.095498
120 08.02.2010            8.01    -0.34391479         8.353915
```

When I write it to a csv sheet it looks like that:

```
write.table(eventStudyList120_After$`Abnormal Returns`, file = "C://Users//AbnormalReturns.csv", sep = ";")
```

[image]

In fact I want to let it look like that:

[image]

So my question is:

How to write the data frame `as it is` into a csv and how to transpose the `Abnormal return` column and put the header as in the example sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches: transpose the data in R or in Excel

**In R**

Add an index column, select the columns you want and **transpose** the data using the function `t`

```
d <- anscombe
d$index <- 1:nrow(anscombe)
td <- t(d[c("index", "x1")])
write.table(td, "filename.csv", col.names = F, sep = ";")
```

Result:

```
"index";1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11
"x1";10;8;13;9;11;14;6;4;12;7;5
```

**In Excel**

Excel allows you to transpose data as well: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/switch-transpose-columns-and-rows-HP010224502.aspx

Comment: Thx for your answer! Is it also possible to remove the index from the result?

Comment: you mean the word index or the whole row?

Comment: I want to replace the whole row by my own row.

Comment: you can export any rows to csv, just include the rows (columns) you need into the dataframe before transposing